# Missing Channel Email address Microsoft Teams API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using [GetChannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get) API to get the web url and email address of the channel however this api does not return email address until a user click on GetEmailAddress on Teams channel action menu. This issue was discussed a year back on [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3927) github thread but not sure if there is any progress or workaround.

We have automated process of creating group, so its not feasible to ask user to click on the GetEmailAddress for every Team. Is there any graph/sharepoint api which we can call to generate channel email?

Comment: This is by design. I am checking internally if there are any updates on this behavior.